# sort_values overwriting style.format

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, jupyter-notebook, format

the code below wouldn't show my format of decimals, sort_values overwrite the previous code and they're not even the same functions

```
items.style.format({"Item Total" : "${:.2f}" , "Item Price" : "${:.2f}"})
 
items.sort_values("Item Count", ascending=False)
```

[image: code result]

Comment: `items.style.format` returns a (html-formated) string, and has nothing to do with `items.sort_values`, which returns a separate dataframe. If you want to see both outputs, put them into two different cells.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in a single cell:

spender= topspend.sort_values("Purchase Count", ascending=False).head()
spender.style.format({"Average Purchase Price": "${:.2f}","Total Purchase Value": "${:.2f}"})

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. Please elaborate your answer so that it may help other users with similar issue in the future.